# send Mail Swiftmailer Symfony doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Hello i try to send email by swift mailer symfony but it doesn't work this is my code

## config.yml

```
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
host: '%mailer_host%'
port: '%mailer_port%'
encryption: '%mailer_encryption%'
username: '%mailer_user%'
password: '%mailer_password%'
spool: { type: memory }
```

## parameters.yml

```
mailer_transport: smtp 
mailer_host: cloud4679.adk-media.com 
mailer_port: 465 
mailer_encryption: SSL 
mailer_user: tst@u3s.ma 
mailer_password: mypassword
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mailer_port: 25 
mailer_encryption: tls
```

please try this and let me know it's work.

Comment: @Sadak Salaheddine If you get your answer then don’t forget to accept